# Render an icon inside NSCell (Cocoa OSX)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4.2, nsoutlineview

I have an **NSOutlineView** and a stack of objects, you can imagine it is a tree of files.

[image: Outline view with icons]

So I tried to extend the **NSTextFieldCell** class to **parse the name of the current item and render an icon for it**. But I am still stuck in the icon part. I simply can't get a standard-hardcoded-image to work!

I tried many tutorials, the only one I got to work is a class called PXSourceList, but it was designed for OSX 10.7+. Also the majority of these tutorials use *AppDelegate* with the **NSOutlineViewDataSource** protocol and I also want the code to be managed elsewhere, not in the *APPDelegate* class.

Can someone give-me some directions on the first steps? I think a bit of enlightenment on how the general logic surrounding the icon thing would be enough. I appreciate!

I use XCode 4.2 for Snow Leopard. The project I'm on is supposed to work in OSX 10.6+, so I can't use the new Lion approach of cells using NSViews.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file icon from its path as follows;

```
NSImage *iconImage1 = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:filepath];
```

You need an image cell to display the icon image.